# Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS or 14.0.4 LTS for building Android Source files?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-source

I am going to setup up a build environment for building Android Source files for AOSP. 
The [AOSP](http://source.android.com) website recommends 12.04 LTS. 
For 14.04 it says

> Building on Ubuntu 14.04 is experimental at the moment but will eventually become the recommended environment.

Can I proceed with the 14.04 instead of fully supported 12.05 or go with the older version and migrate later on? 
What would be best recommended?

Comment: I'm not any sort of authority on the subject, hence why I'm leaving a comment instead of any answer, but you should have no problem building AOSP on 14.04. That is actually the version of Ubuntu that I use to build AOSP and I don't see any messages anywhere during build which implies that it's a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. All I was fearing is errors due to the environment versions. But if it is not a case, then I will go for 14.04

Comment: Did you use a VM to install Ubuntu or directly to the HDD? Last time,  using a VM running 14.04 Ubuntu, I couldnt sync the repository. It hung up at certain point. May be the due to the Scaling issues. Tried all recommended solutions. Couldnt find a way out.

Comment: I've built on both. Same process.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how confident you are in understanding/fixing the problems you find along the way, or if you just want to have a working environment with minimal chances of problems.

By using 14.04LTS and providing feedback, you can contribute to make the experimental version to become the recommended one, so if you have the time and energy, and are not depending on it for your work, I'd recommend to try 14.04LTS version.

Good luck!